# Neo4j shell import throws - Unknown command 'foreach'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Tried with Neo4j version 2.1.7 / 2.2.0
CQL contains =>
FOREACH (name in ["Hindu","Muslim","Christian","Jain"] | CREATE (:Religion {title:name}) );

I'm unable to import this using neo4j shell. err thrown : Unknown command 'foreach'.

I'm generating the CQL file through PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `neo4j-shell` is not aware that a valid cypher statement can start with `FOREACH`. A simple workaround is to begin with a `WITH`:

```
with ["Hindu","Muslim","Christian","Jain"] as r 
foreach (name in r|create (:Religion{title:name}));
```

Comment: Best!! Worked..Thanks